# how to come back from using pageViewController to the start view

Tags: ios, xcode, back, uipageviewcontroller

sounds easy and hopefully it is, but I´m lost.

I have
  1. view controller as initial scene, then I build up 
  2. the `pageViewController` (with the `childViewController`) as several books/articels/apple explained.

Everything works perfect. Now, my problem is, what do I have to do, when I **want to leave the `pageViewController` and going back to the initial scene** (i.e. the very first controller)?

Background: I have a little app and what to show a tutorial first (which is using the `pageViewController`) using Xcode 5 and ios7

Thanks a lot, please help me even if it may sound very easy

```
 // Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: How are you presenting the pageviewcontroller?  Are you using a storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on segues as they make it much simpler to present a new `UIViewController` when you are using storyboards.   What your code actually does is instantiate your new view controller and put it over the top of all of the elements that are currently on the screen.

You can remove it by calling

```
[self.pageViewController.view removeFromSuperView];
[self.pageViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: thx, thats it perfect. The code is actually from a tutorial will try it with segues in a minute.